# Itextsharp customize password message

Tags: c#, itext

[image]

Hi, can I customize the message to "Please enter your birthday and last 6 digit of card" in pdf enrypted file using Itextsharp PdfEncryptor?

```
  public byte[] GenerateSoaCrystalPdf(SoaCustomerViewModel customer, out int totalPages, bool encryptFile = false)
    {
        var rptDoc = GenerateSoaCrystal(customer);
        // process PDF file
        var stream = rptDoc.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat);
        // dispose the report document
        rptDoc.Close();
        rptDoc.Dispose();

        // create password-protected PDF
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            if (encryptFile)
            {
                // count number of pages
                using (var pdfReader = new PdfReader(stream))
                {
                    totalPages = pdfReader.NumberOfPages;
                    var password = customer.DateOfBirth + customer.CardNumber.NumbersOnly().Right(6);
                    PdfEncryptor.Encrypt(pdfReader, ms, true, password, password, PdfWriter.AllowScreenReaders);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // TODO: fix error when calling PdfReader
                totalPages = 0;
                stream.CopyTo(ms);
            }
            return ms.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

As far as I'm aware, no you cannot because this message is defined by the PDF reader used to view the document.

Comment: True, but also: there's nothing in ISO 32000 (the PDF specification) that supports the requirement. So the answer is indeed: *No, this can't be done. Not with iText, not with any other tool.*